# Docker failed starting Clickhouse-server container 21.11 on M1 chip MacOS

Tags: docker, apple-m1, clickhouse

I am trying to start a clickhouse-server container on an m1 chip MacOS system, unfortunately it throws following errors and keeps restarting by itself.

- Docker Desktop:`4.6.1 (76265)`
- Clickhouse-server image: `yandex/clickhouse-server:21.11`

I am wondering whether anyone encountered similar issue can share some thoughts? Thanks

```
❯ docker run -it -p 9000:9000 -p 9009:9009 -p 8123:8123 --platform linux/amd64 --ulimit nofile=262144:262144 yandex/clickhouse-server:21.11
runtime: failed to create new OS thread (have 2 already; errno=22)
fatal error: newosproc

runtime stack:
runtime.throw(0x4cb21f, 0x9)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:566 +0x95
runtime.newosproc(0xc420028000, 0xc420037fc0)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/os_linux.go:160 +0x194
runtime.newm(0x4d6db8, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:1572 +0x132
runtime.main.func1()
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:126 +0x36
runtime.systemstack(0x53ae00)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:298 +0x79
runtime.mstart()
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:1079

goroutine 1 [running]:
runtime.systemstack_switch()
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:252 fp=0xc420022768 sp=0xc420022760
runtime.main()
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:127 +0x6c fp=0xc4200227c0 sp=0xc420022768
runtime.goexit()
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2086 +0x1 fp=0xc4200227c8 sp=0xc4200227c0
Configuration file '/etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml' isn't readable by user with id '101'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's expected. You need to use ARM images

https://hub.docker.com/r/altinity/clickhouse-server/tags?page=1&name=arm

try image altinity/clickhouse-server:21.12.3.32.altinitydev.arm

Comment: Thanks Denny. I have tried `lunalabsltd/clickhouse-server:21.7.2.7-arm` and it worked.

Comment: @denny are these stable?

Comment: @Switch386 now you can get the official image with ARM support https://hub.docker.com/r/clickhouse/clickhouse-server/tags?page=1 , see linux/amd64 / linux/arm64